# Rendering text on GPU metal vs CPU core graphics

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I’m trying to decide if it’s a good idea to render text to video on low level metal GPU or just keep using core graphics to draw text on video frame.

Using the GPU seems like a couple months of work to get it right and even then is simple static rendering. 
Will I see significant gains in performance if I change to GPU?
I’m doing animated video captions renderer app and the text on metal seems complex.

I already got the metal pipeline running with some drawing

Comment: One thing you can try is to use the CALayer.drawsAsynchronously flag -- that makes CoreGraphics render using the GPU and you can check if that speeds up your text rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will I see significant gains in performance if I change to gpu ?

It depends on a lot of factors, but you'll get a significant improvement anyway. In my program I have to deal with high resolution video (**16K**, **60FPS**), and without native text rendering, my program simply will not work.

> Using the gpu seems like a couple months of work to get it right and
>   even then is simple static rendering.

It wouldn't take that long, there are so many articles in the web, here are some of them:

[Rendering Text in Metal](https://metalbyexample.com/rendering-text-in-metal-with-signed-distance-fields/)

[Rendering Text in OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering)

[Text Rendering Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Text_rendering_libraries)

Comment: what do you mean by "and without native text rendering, my program simply will not work."  thank you

Comment: I'm doing real-time video processing at 16K resolution, and if I render text to video on CPU, my program will simply slow down terribly. You're welcome!

Comment: Another thing to consider: if your going down the route of rendering text yourself with your own font atlas etc, it may provide a problem down the road in supporting different localisations that don't use a latin alphabet, or that don't use an alphabet at all like Simplified Chinese, Japanese etc..

Comment: That's good. I am wondering if I can replace CoreAnimation altogether and have a single Metal rendering engine for video frames. Using Core Text would be okay to render along with Metal though.